# Marking questions as duplicate

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

People have been marking one of my questions as a duplicate. I'm confused on how they did it when I saw `[duplicate]` on the title and a message saying that mine is a duplicate of a different question. It is on my other account, but you get the idea. I tried adding it to a title, but that didn't work. I tried using the flag, but that didn't work either. How do I mark a question as a duplicate?
Also, I will be very sad if you mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Which question, @fishfinboy?

Comment: I think someone should edit out “also, I will be very sad if you mark this question as a duplicate.”

Comment: So @TheMattbat999, I'm doing the question, "How do I mark a question as a duplicate?"

Answer (score 5):

Arqade is moderated by the community, but before you get access to all the moderation features we have to trust that you won't use them for bad things. The 'reputation' number next to a user's name is a kind of measure of how much that user is trusted, it's based on votes of your questions and answers.

More rep, more trust, more '[Privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)' you can earn, including community-moderating functions like 'Closing' (and Reopening) questions.

Questions can be closed for many reasons, including being a 'duplicate' of a previous question. So how did they do it?

1. A user saw your question
2. They located a question that they believe yours is a duplicate of (maybe yours reminded them of the older question).
3. They went back to your question, clicked 'Close'->'Duplicate of', and pasted the link to the question.
4. Finally, they clicked 'Close'.

This action places your question into a review queue, as well as linking the other question in the comments if it wasn't already. At this point, the community must review the decision - 4 other users must agree that, yes, this question is a duplicate of another question and should be closed.

If you believe this was in error, the best thing you can do is to *edit your question* to clarify it and explain how yours is fundamentally a different question from the duplication target. By editing your question, this again bumps it into a review queue, this time to see if the question should be reopened following your updates & changes.

A lot of these topics and more are covered in more depth on the Help Center. For further reading: on the Top bar, click the question mark icon, then go to 'Help Center':

[image: Question Mark Icon on Top Bar]

---

As for why this happens, from our Help Center article on [Duplicates](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates):

> ### Why are some questions marked as duplicate?
>
> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. This does not mean that every duplicate will immediately be closed; we love (some) dupes. There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way.